# Paint of the door is peeling right after paint repair?

Tags: honda, paint, paint-scratches

Just got my car from paint shop, driver and passenger doors were painted because of car accident.

What could cause what can be seen on photos below? Poorly done work? I want to take car back to them, but I need some arguments about **why** this could be bad in long term.

And actually, is this really something I should worry about?

[image: Front door]
[image: Rear door]

And here's a photo from the accident, I was hit by another car.

[image]

Comment: Take it back to the shop and have them fix it. This should be covered under warranty of the fix. Most shops (at least here in the States) have lifetime a warranty on their work. Regardless, this should have been taken care of at the shop and they should be the one fixing it free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the photos, I would think that the edges were not blown in, just the "faces" or flat parts of the doors - that edge damage (chips etc) was there before the accident I would think. You should go back to them but get another professional opinion stating what is incorrect first.

Comment: Thank you! I added a photo of the doors before the repair. I definetely will go to another professionals before that. I just wondering how bad it is.